# After changing the .env file, is it enough to execute "docker-compose up d" to apply changes?

Tags: docker, server, configuration, environment, jitsi

firstly I wanna start by saying that I am not familier with servers and Docker. So take it easy on me.
I am making some changes to a server I connected through google console cloud. The changes are in the `.env` file. I made some configuration changes. Then I know that I have to do something like close the server and restart it for the changes to apply. I executed `docker-compose up -d` but what I wanted did not happen. So maybe I should have said `docker-compose down` or the reason it did not happen was because of my code in the server?

This thing is for a self-hosted jitsi (video conferencing) server. I am trying to activate the jwt token authentication option. Here's my changes in the .env file:

```
#Enable authentication
ENABLE_AUTH=1
# Enable guest access
ENABLE_GUESTS=0
# Select authentication type: internal, jwt or ldap
AUTH_TYPE=jwt
# JWT authentication
# Application identifier
JWT_APP_ID= myıd
JWT_APP_SECRET=myscret
```

Comment: what are those configuration? related to db?

Comment: It ıs about enablıng authectication and sepcifying application id and secret for jwt tokens

Comment: @Mukit09 what was I suppose to do if it was related to db?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] demonstrating your issue. A `docker-compose down` is not necessary.

Comment: @BMitch I added it.

Comment: @codertryer that's not a reproducible example, there's no compose file or image to run, or commands run showing the env changes didn't apply.

Comment: I dont know how to add a compose file and I am not sure if the changes applied or did not apply. I know that my program is not working as I want it. Thus, it could be because of the server changes did not apply or some configuration steps I took are missing. I want to know which one ıs the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimum reproducible example showing that you do not need to run a `docker-compose down` to see the changes from the `.env` file:

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml 
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    image: busybox
    container_name: test-env
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    environment:
      message: ${message}

$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "64553060_default" with the default driver
Creating test-env ... done

$ cat .env
message=hello world

$ docker exec test-env env | grep message
message=hello world

$ vi .env

$ docker-compose up -d
Recreating test-env ... done

$ cat .env
message=hello stackoverflow

$ docker exec test-env env | grep message
message=hello stackoverflow
```